# How to make a program wait for the process to open before functioning?

Tags: c++, winapi

Let me explain it a bit more here:
I'm going to `WriteProcessMemory` in `C++`, however I want the program to wait until the specific process is open before writing to the process memory. How do I do that?
For example:
Say I want to write to a process called `joel.exe`.
I want to change the value on address `0x01234567` to `4`.
what I want to figure out is how do I make it wait for the process `joel.exe` to start up before changing the value to `4`.

I have a brief understanding of `C++` and am still in the beginners area.
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Gamer, and welcome to StackOverflow.  I'm afraid your question doesn't give much in the way of information. What have you tried already?  Without know the context, sadly the community can't help you.  It sounds to me like you'd put it in a thread, and then wait for it to finish, but that's way beyond a beginner topic.  Please post what you've tried so far and any error messages, or if you can, flesh it out more telling us what you plan to use etc.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I truley don't know how to do it, I found the WriteProcessMemory on YouTube. I found this place to be helpful so I tried asking the question.

Comment: Fair enough Gamer, but the question I have is why are you writing it? In what context are you planning to use it?  That will help us to help you come to an answer.

Comment: And just seen you've edited ;-)

Comment: I found a whitelist on google, so I thought i'd test it. I tweaked it to whitelist based on a games userIds, so what i'm trying to do is see if you change the userId just as soon as you join the server, would you bypass it? That's why i'm trying to do this, that and as well expand my knowledge.

Comment: `CreateProcess` doesn't return, until the process has been created. Whatever you mean by *"open"* is dubious, at best.

Comment: In practical terms you need to wait until the memory location in question has been allocated and initialized.  There is no universal solution, it depends on the details of the target executable.  If it isn't your own executable, trial and error is probably the only approach.

Comment: You can potentially use [WaitForInputIdle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but if the program in question does not have a message loop it won't do what you want.  I assume you're starting the second program with CreateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, if the process you are waiting on has a window, and you know the window caption, you can use [`FindWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) to find the window HANDLE, then use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the Process ID, then finally use [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx) to open that process. If you do a periodic run on `FindWindow()` you should achieve what you want to do.